# Correct way to move to another page in my app

Tags: c#, silverlight

I a new to Silverlight and I want to make sure I do this in the "correct" way (if there is one).

Say I am showing MainPage.xaml and I want to have a button click move me to ADifferentPage.xaml (after the OnButtonClick is run).

What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: Wow!  I though this would be a no brainer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Silverlight Navigation Application Project Template. And use the Navigation frame to navigate to other pages.
Please have a look at the UriMapper too in the main page.
So, on the button click event you can use the `NavigationService.Navigate()` method.